# Recommend way to start a php session in an ExpresionEngine module?

Tags: php, session, module, expressionengine

What is the recommended way to start a php session in an EE module.

I am using EE 2.9.4 and have a custom module. In the constructor I call session_start(). When I look at the cookie that gets created the cookie path is wrong. It is set to the path of the page instead of "/".

When I call session_start in a plain php app the default behavior of session_start is to set the cookie path at root "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this feature but have you looked at the Cookie Settings in the Control Panel?

Admin > Security and Privacy > Cookie Settings

Try setting a value for `Cookie Path`